# How to get current marker's name via python?

Tags: python, marker

I wanted to check if any camera is binded to the current marker.
For that I thought I would simply compare the marker's name with the active camera's name (bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].camera).
But cant't understand how to get the current marker's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each marker has a camera and a name property. Easy to figure out using the python console:

```
>>> C.scene.timeline_markers['F_01'].
                                     as_pointer(
                                     bl_rna
                                     camera
                                     ...
                                     name
                                     ...
```

To get the cameras just iterate through the markers:

```
>>> for m in C.scene.timeline_markers:
...     print ("Marker name:", m.name)
...     print ("Camera object:", m.camera)
...     print ("Camera name:", m.camera.name)
...     
Marker name: F_01
Camera object: <bpy_struct, Object("Camera")>
Camera name: Camera
```

Comment: Many thanks, It helped me a lot!